# WinCVS v2.0.2.4 - external diff is not working

Tags: wincvs

I have installed WinCVS and I am trying to use external diff for looking diff file.
I have tried with WinMerge and Beyond Compare but none were getting launched when launched diff.
I already have specified external diff full path in Preferences, checked the check box but things are not working.

Answer (score 1):

http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/info-cvs/2001-03/msg00482.html

> when starting the diff you get the "diff settings" window.  You have
>   to check the checkbox "use the external diff". Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

By some reason WinCvs sometimes does not update registry flag for using external diff. In this case you can do it manually by setting following registry data:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\WinCvs\wincvs\CVS settings]
"P_DiffUseExtDiff"=hex:01
```